# how update fontawesome version without updating bootstrap version?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

My rails 3.2.13 app has bootstrap_and_overrides.css which refers to fontawesome:
=require twitter-bootstrap-static/fontawesome

That is the only explicit reference to fontawesome in my code, eg, fontaweseom seems to be 'baked into' my version of twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.6).

How can I add the newest fontwawesome goodies (3.2) to my rails app without changing my bootstrap version?

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of fontawesome from their website, replace the existing css files with the new one that you have downloaded. Also, please make sure that you replace the fonts folder too.

Comment: That would work if I was using it standalone. But I'm using it bundled with Twitter bootstrap rails gem, so there does not seem to be a separate css etc... it's part of the gem. Trying to update the new font symbosl without changing my bootstrap version. So it's probably a combination of downloading the latest fotnawesome stuff, and ALSO somehow disaling the verison that's embedded in the bootstrap gem.

Comment: am sorry @jpwynn as i don't know about rails. however I got https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails this while googling. am not sure it helps. i answered in general terms. should i delete the answer?